# What other "Superdrives" are able to replace the UJ-868?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I suspect my MacBook Pro's Superdrive is faulty. It refuses to burn Sony DVD+R discs.
I'm now looking at replacing the drive, but I see there are many "Superdrives". I have a Matshita DVD-R UJ-868, but I see different type numbers are sold as a Superdrive.

Which Superdrives, besides the UJ-868, are compatible with my 15 inch, mid 2009 MacBook Pro 5,3?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am in the same boat.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. Otherwise I would've posted it here :)

Comment: I have decide to just buy a drive from Amazon, http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00B5L3EH4?keywords=uj868&qid=1451827057&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1. $51 new isn't a bad deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A drive to replace the Matshita UJ-868 should be:

- 9.5mm in height
- SATA interface
- Slot loading

You can even replace it with a UJ-267 (which is a Blu-ray writer)